# Stack implementation by list code review, is my solution correct?

Tags: c#

I've had homework to do for my programming lectures, and I don't know that is my solution correct?
I've had to implement stack by the list, but I don't know am I understood it correctly.

Sorry for my English :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Zad._20
{
    class Element
    {
        public String value;
        public Element previous;

        public Element(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Zad._20
{
    class Stack
    {
        private Element top;

        public Stack()  {
            top = null;
        }

        public void Push(Element e)  {
            e.previous = top;
            top = e;
        }

        public void Pop()  {
            top = top.previous;
        }

        public void Print()    {
            while(top != null) {
                Console.WriteLine(top.value);
                top = top.previous;
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you're supposed to tell us what doesn't work, and if everything worked you would go to the Code Review site to have it validated. I can spot an issue in `Print()`, though: it invalidates the stack - try calling it twice in a row.

Comment: It seems, you are trying to implement `Stack` via *linked list*, not *list*

Comment: @DmitryBychenko So how it should look via list? Can you explain me? :)

Comment: You would need a pointer which is an index to point to the top element, push would use the add method ans pop would use the removeat method from List

Comment: @Daras: `List` (in terms of C#), e.g. `List<T>` is an array like collection in which you can `Add` items as well as `Remove` (`RemoveAt`) them.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that you are trying to implement `Stack<T>` via [LinkedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.8) (well known classical problem), not [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8); if you insist on `List<T>`
the code will be quite simple. Your code rewritten to `List<T>`:

```
  // <T> - let's have a generic stack, e.g. MyStack<int> or MyStack<String>
  public class MyStack<T> {
    // List<T> in which we store the stack's items
    private List<T> m_Items = new List<T>();

    // Nothing to write home about; we can safely drop this constructor
    public MyStack() {}

    public void Push(T item) {
      // Just add item to the items
      m_Items.Add(item);
    }

    public T Pop() {
      // We can't Pop an item from the empty stack
      if (m_Items.Count <= 0) 
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Stack is empty");
      else {
        // Take the last item
        T result = m_Items[m_Items.Count - 1];

        // Remove it (the last item) from the list
        m_Items.RemoveAt(m_Items.Count - 1);

        // Return the last item
        return result;
      }
    }

    public void Print() {
      // Print out all the items in reversed order
      for (int i = m_Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
        Console.WriteLine(m_Items[i]);
    }
  }
```